# How to correctly convert from world to camera space using convert_space()?

Tags: python, transforms, coordinates

I'm trying to use the python API to get the transformation matrix from world space to camera space. I want to do this by using `convert_space()` but I don't manage to get the correct transformation matrix and the documentation is also not helpful. Shouldn't it be as simple as that?

```
m_world_to_camera = camera.convert_space(matrix=mathutils.Matrix.Identity(4),from_space='WORLD',to_space='LOCAL')
```

The transformation somehow neglects the camera's translation. On the other hand

```
m_world_to_camera = camera.matrix_world.inverted()
```

gives me the correct transformation. I could use this instead but I want to figure out what's wrong with my understanding of `convert_space()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue with your method is that the `convert_space` method only converts the rotations, not the translations. To get the complete transformation matrix, you can apply both rotation and translation by concatenating the rotation matrix obtained from `convert_space` with the camera's world position. Try this:

```
import bpy
import mathutils

camera = bpy.data.objects['Camera']

rotation_matrix = camera.convert_space(matrix=mathutils.Matrix.Identity(4), from_space='WORLD', to_space='LOCAL')
translation_vector = camera.matrix_world.to_translation()
m_world_to_camera = rotation_matrix @ mathutils.Matrix.Translation(translation_vector)
```

Comment: Yes, that seems like it. Would be nice if the documentation would be more clear about this and state that `convert_space` neglects the translation.